# Get off days from Google holidays calendar

Tags: jquery, api, google-calendar-api

How can i get the national holidays from a google calendar using the developers API?
I have the code to get the holidays, that's working, but i need to skip for example Valentine's Day because that's not a day off.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/' + calendarid + '/events?key=' + mykey,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            self.NationalHolidays(data.items);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            //tell that an error has occurred
        }
    });
```

Tnx!

Comment: Please post what you have tried already, code wise

Comment: A list with calendar id's can be found here https://gist.github.com/mattn/1438183